# Bash: How do I add an element to an array that is stored in a variable?

Tags: python, node.js, bash, git, npm

**TL;DR**

I have two array variables in bash, `archPkgs` and `npmPkgs`. Later in my code I have a variable variable, `pkgPlatform`, that can point to either of these. I want to add an element to the array through this variable variable. How can I do that in bash?

**Details**

I am trying to write a post-installation script in Python and Bash, and I am working on one of the bast scripts that installs all of the needed packages. Below is the code for it.

```
# List of all Arch packages
archPkgs=(
        # Display server
        'xorg'

        # Display manager
        'lightdm'
        'lightdm-webkit2-greeter'
        'lightdm-webkit-theme-litarvan'

        # Editor
        'neovim-nightly-bin'

        # WM
        'i3-gaps'
        'i3lock'
        'i3status'
        'picom'
        'rofi'

        # Syncing
        'syncthing'

        # Printing
        'cups'

        # Networking
        'network-manager-applet'
        'avahi'
        'nss-mdns'
        'reflector'

        # Browsing
        'firefox'
        'firefox-nightly'

        # Terminals, shell, programming, and other programsn and utilities
        'kitty'
        'bash-completion'
        'nodejs'
        'npm'
        'python'
        'python-pip'

        # Notifications
        'dunst'

        # Gaming
        'steam'

        # Media
        'vlc'
        'playerctl'
        'spotify'

        # Audio
        'pasystray'
        'pulseaudio'
        'pulseaudio-alsa'
        'pulseaudio-bluetooth'
        'pavucontrol'
        'lib32-libpulse'
        'lib32-alsa-plugins'
        'alsa-utils'
        'alsa-firmware'

        # Fonts
        'noto-fonts-cjk'
        'noto-fonts-emoji'
        'ttf-iosevka'
        'ttf-liberation'
        'ttf-opensans'

        # Drive tools + backups
        'udiskie'
        'borg'

        # Power management
        'xfce4-power-manager'

        # Themes
        'arc-gtk-theme'
        'breeze'

        # Screenshots
        'flameshot'

        # Bluetooth
        'blueman'
        'bluez'
        'bluez-utils'
)

npmPkgs=(
    # Language servers
    'vim-language-server'
    'bash-language-server'

    # Type checkers
    'pyright'
)


while true; do
    echo Are there any packages you would like to manage? Enter [arch/npm] [add/remove][ name of package].
    read pkgPlatform pkgAction pkgName

    if [ "$pkgPlatform" == 'arch' ]; then
        pkgPlatform=archPkgs
    elif [ "$pkgPlatform" == 'npm' ]; then
        pkgPlatform=npmPkgs

    elif [ "$pkgPlatform" == 'quit' ] || [ "$pkgAction" == 'quit' ] || [ "$pkgAction" == 'quit' ]; then
        echo Continuing...
        break

    else
        echo "Unknown option."
        continue
    fi

    if [ "$pkgPlatform" != 'quit' ] && [ "$pkgAction" != 'quit' ] && [ "$pkgName" != 'quit' ]; then
        while true; do
            if [ "$pkgAction" == 'add' ]; then
                $pkgPlatform+=pkgName
                break

            elif [ "$pkgAction" == 'remove' ]; then
                unset "$pkgName"[$pkgPlatform]
                break
```

Whenever I run it, this is what happens.

```
[johnny@lj-laptop post_install_scripts]$ ./02_pkgs.sh 
Packages to be installed:

Arch Packages
xorg lightdm lightdm-webkit2-greeter lightdm-webkit-theme-litarvan neovim-nightly-bin i3-gaps i3lock i3status picom rofi syncthing cups network-manager-applet avahi nss-mdns reflector firefox firefox-nightly kitty bash-completion nodejs npm python python-pip dunst steam vlc playerctl spotify pasystray pulseaudio pulseaudio-alsa pulseaudio-bluetooth pavucontrol lib32-libpulse lib32-alsa-plugins alsa-utils alsa-firmware noto-fonts-cjk noto-fonts-emoji ttf-iosevka ttf-liberation ttf-opensans udiskie borg xfce4-power-manager arc-gtk-theme breeze flameshot blueman bluez bluez-utils

npm Packages
vim-language-server bash-language-server pyright
Are there any packages you would like to manage? Enter [arch/npm] [add/remove] [name of package].
When you are satisfied, enter "quit" instead of "add" or "remove".
npm add test
./02_pkgs.sh: line 153: npmPkgs+=pkgName: command not found
Packages to be installed:

Arch Packages
xorg lightdm lightdm-webkit2-greeter lightdm-webkit-theme-litarvan neovim-nightly-bin i3-gaps i3lock i3status picom rofi syncthing cups network-manager-applet avahi nss-mdns reflector firefox firefox-nightly kitty bash-completion nodejs npm python python-pip dunst steam vlc playerctl spotify pasystray pulseaudio pulseaudio-alsa pulseaudio-bluetooth pavucontrol lib32-libpulse lib32-alsa-plugins alsa-utils alsa-firmware noto-fonts-cjk noto-fonts-emoji ttf-iosevka ttf-liberation ttf-opensans udiskie borg xfce4-power-manager arc-gtk-theme breeze flameshot blueman bluez bluez-utils

npm Packages
vim-language-server bash-language-server pyright
Are there any packages you would like to manage? Enter [arch/npm] [add/remove] [name of package].
When you are satisfied, enter "quit" instead of "add" or "remove".
```

The issue looks to be in line 153.

I'm not very sure what my options are at this point. I pasted the script with all of the system-changing lines commented out, but you should still take a look at it before you run it.

Obviously the script isn't done yet, and I plan on rearranging a lot of stuff earlier.

Comment: This would be a much better question of your reduced it to a minimal example that only showed the issue, rather than give us your whole script and make us figure it out.

Comment: Nonetheless, in bash, you can declare and array with `declare -a array_var`. Google "bash array variables" and you will find many pages answering your question. If you cannot figure it out, please ask a targeted question with a minimal example.

Comment: @joanis alright, I cut down the script a bit. I also tried that variable out, but it still isn't working. I changed the arrays I the top of the script to `declare -a arrayname()`

Comment: the `+=` syntax you used is not appropriate for arrays. My recommended Google search gave me this page: https://opensource.com/article/18/5/you-dont-know-bash-intro-bash-arrays look for "Populating arrays" in there.

Comment: [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) has some tips like `Line 125: $pkgPlatform+=pkgName SC2281: Don't use $ on the left side of assignments.`

Comment: re: `$pkgPlatform+=pkgName` ...you've got the `$` on the wrong side, I'm assuming you want: `pkgPlatform+=$pkgName` (NOTE: not saying this will do what you want, but it should be a start for getting past the syntax error)

Comment: I'll suggest to change this `if\elif\else` block to `case` it would be much better.

Comment: Added TL;DR at the top of this question to pinpoint the issue to make its focus more clear. Also voting to reopen, I think this question about accessing bash arrays through a variable variable is of good value to future bash programmers and should be reopened. It just needed to be made more clear.

Answer (score 4):

Change

```sh
    if [ "$pkgPlatform" == 'arch' ]; then
        pkgPlatform=archPkgs
    elif [ "$pkgPlatform" == 'npm' ]; then
        pkgPlatform=npmPkgs
```

to

```sh
    if [ "$pkgPlatform" == 'arch' ] || [ "$pkgPlatform" == 'npm' ]; then
        declare -n platformPkgs="${pkgPlatform}Pkgs"
```

That makes `platformPkgs` a **nameref** to the desired array. You then use `platformPkgs` like a normal array variable.

Then change

```sh
            if [ "$pkgAction" == 'add' ]; then
                $pkgPlatform+=pkgName
                break

            elif [ "$pkgAction" == 'remove' ]; then
                unset "$pkgName"[$pkgPlatform]
                break
```

to

```sh
            if [ "$pkgAction" == 'add' ]; then
                platformPkgs+=( "$pkgName" )
                break

            elif [ "$pkgAction" == 'remove' ]; then
                ## not this => unset "platformPkgs[$pkgName]"
                # first, iterate through the array to find
                # the index for this value $pkgName,
                # then, unset "platformPkgs[$index]"
                # or rewrite the array except for the element at that index: 
                #   platformPkgs=( "${platformPkgs[@]:0:index}" "${platformPkgs[@]:index+1}" )
                break
```

Comment: What is the point of this line, and what does the `Pkgs` at the end do?

Comment: Alright, it seems to work. Thanks for that. I did notice that it doesn't remove entries like it is supposed to. I could add `vim` to the list and run the command to remove it, and it instead removes the first entry in the list. What could be causing this?

Comment: Oh, right, these are numerically indexed arrays, so the string in $pkgName is getting coerced to zero (through arithmetic expansion that I won't get into here). Since you want to remove one of the array elements, you'll have to iterate through the array to find the index matching the element and then unset that array index.

Answer (score 2):

What you *want* line 153 to execute is

```
npmPkgs+=($pkgName)
```

but you've got your target variable in a variable itself.  Remember that the shell's first love is constructing command lines, variable substitution is only done where you've pointed the shell at it with a `$` operator.

The brute-force way to do this is

```
eval $pkgPlatform'+=($pkgname)'
```

which does your target-name substitution and then rescans the resulting line.

As an unrelated note, you could clean that script up *a lot* with some case statements.

Answer (score -1):

the error you face is because you have not append the item to the array correctly,

```
$pkgPlatform+=pkgName ##that way the bash script can't get what you mean
```

so, when you add an item to the variable `pkgPlatform`, it can be done as follows:

```
pkgPlatform+=("$pkgName")
```

Comment: This is incorrect: variable expansions don't go on the left-hand side of `=`

Comment: the mistake is not with expansion, it is with using `$` on the left hand side. I will edit my answer.

Comment: The `$` makes it an expansion: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion